# How to mock helper functions in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, unit-testing, jestjs, google-cloud-functions

I am currently exploring unit-testing in Firebase Cloud Functions and ran into a use-case that seems like it would be quite frequent but isn't covered by the official documentation.

When writing Cloud Functions for various processes and triggers, we usually use separate helper functions to help us write more reusable code. For example:

```
// index.ts
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

function add(num1: number, num2: number) {
    return num1 + num2;
}

exports.getSum = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return {
        result: add(data.num1, data.num2)
    }
})
```

When I now want to test `getSum`, I would have to import it into my test file and make an assertion. However this is where I encounter the issue:

How do I assert that `add` has been called in `getSum`? Or better: how do I mock `add`?

The only workaround I have found so far is exporting `add` as well and then modifying the code to call `this.add` instead of just `add` like so:

```
// index.ts
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export function add(num1: number, num2: number) {
    return num1 + num2;
}

exports.getSum = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return {
        // @ts-ignore
        result: this.add(data.num1, data.num2)
    }
})
```

However this solution is not ideal as I 1. can't guarantee that `this` isn't undefined (which is also why I need to `// @ts-ignore` it) and 2. need to modify the original code to make testing work.

Is there any way to make this work without modifying the functions code? Any best practice for testing these kind of helper functions? Thank you in advance!

Here is the full unit test code I have used for the workaround:

```
// index.unit.test.ts
const testEnvironment = require("firebase-functions-test")(
  {
    databaseURL: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        projectId: "",
    },
    "credentials.json"
  );
  const myFunctions = require("../src/index");


describe("getSum", () => {
    let wrapper: any, group: any;

    beforeAll(() => {
        group = myFunctions.addition
        wrapper = testEnvironment.wrap(group.getSum);
    });

    it("adds two numbers", () => {    
        group.add = jest.fn()
    
        wrapper({ num1: 2, num2: 2})

        expect(group.add).toHaveBeenCalled()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) package to mock the `add` function without modifying your code. For simplicity, I will use [offline mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#offline-mode) to test the code. Just to demonstrate how to mock the `add` function.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

function add(num1: number, num2: number) {
  return num1 + num2;
}

exports.getSum = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return {
    result: add(data.num1, data.num2),
  };
});
```

`index.unit.test.ts`

```
const testEnvironment = require("firebase-functions-test")();
const rewire = require("rewire");

describe("getSum", () => {
  it("adds two numbers", () => {
    const mod = rewire("./");
    const mAdd = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(666);
    mod.__set__("add", mAdd);
    const wrapper = testEnvironment.wrap(mod.getSum);
    const actual = wrapper({ num1: 2, num2: 2 });
    console.log(actual);
    expect(actual).toEqual({ result: 666 });
    expect(mAdd).toBeCalledWith(2, 2);
  });
});
```

npm script:

```json
"test:cjs": "ts-node -O '{\"module\":\"commonjs\"}' node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
```

Run unit test with coverage report

```
npm run test:cjs -- --coverage ./index.unit.test.ts
```

unit test result:

```
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variables are missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail"}
 PASS  stackoverflow/65763396/index.unit.test.ts
  getSum
    ✓ adds two numbers (433ms)

  console.log
    { result: 666 }

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/65763396/index.unit.test.ts:11:13)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.316s, estimated 3s
```

package versions:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.3",
    "jest": "^25.5.4",
    "rewire": "^5.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^25.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^7.4.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.1"
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Using `"module": "commonjs"` seems to break the `firebase-functions-test` config though. I am getting the same warning as you do in my tests, however the tests also fail as I use `firebase-admin` in my functions as well. Any idea as to why it breaks and how to fix it?

Comment: EDIT: Just figured out is does NOT seem to be related to `"module": "commonjs"`. But still fails saying `process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT is not set.`.

Comment: @Aside It's probably that I am testing the code using **Offline mode**. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#offline-mode